# Oracle sql: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have looked into why this error occurs but I couldn't find any helpful answer. One person answered for another question that its because in the sql statement, the column name used for multiple tables may be the same. However, I tried to change that and yet I got the same error. Here is my sql statement:-

```
SELECT CLASSID INTO V_ID FROM CLASSES INNER JOIN BOOKING ON BOOKING.CLASSID=CLASSES.CLASSID WHERE BOOKING.BOOKINGID=:NEW.BOOKING_ID;
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be :

```
SELECT BOOKING.CLASSID INTO V_ID FROM CLASSES INNER JOIN BOOKING  ON BOOKING.CLASSID=CLASSES.CLASSID WHERE BOOKING.BOOKINGID=:NEW.BOOKING_ID
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Will mark your answer as best after 9 minutes

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
Bo.CLASSID INTO V_ID
 FROM CLASSES cl INNER JOIN BOOKING bo ON     
BO.CLASSID=Cl.CLASSID WHERE  
BO.BOOKINGID=:NEWBOOKING_ID;
```

Try this. Your classid column exist in both tables.  You have to explicitly choose classid column of which table you want select. In your select list in place of classid you should write booking.classid or classess.classid.

I added alias for table names. Bo for booking and cl for classess. This helps make code more compact. And in place of table name i have written alias name.